# Capturing one bishop

Tags: strategy, tactics, bishops, bad-bishop

I was just looking for the best move in the position (White to move).

And I thought that capturing the bishop in green square would be the best as it controls

the open a8-h1 diagonal ,but the engine preferred the bishop in red square with an advantage over 2 points in its evaluation,

I am unable to see the reason (tactical or strategic)
 for this behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.Bxb2 and you're up a rook for a pawn.

1.Qxd1 Bxe5 and you're only up the exchange (rook vs bishop) for a pawn.

Comment: lol, you are right , I just blundered in basic calculation haha!